# Summing returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a very lame question. But i don't know how to solve it.

I am trying to add two float numbers(eg: 1.0583389964654335) in a loop, which of 1500 length.

```
    var distance = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i< latArray.length;i++)
    {
        var s = GCDistance(latArray[i],lonArray[i],latArray[i+1],lonArray[i+1]);
        distance = parseFloat(distance) + parseFloat(s);

        alert(distance);    
    }


        var radius = 6378137.0 ; // earth radius
        var DE2RA = 0.01745329252; // degre to radian conversion

        GCDistance= function (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
            //console.log(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
            if (lat1 == lat2 && lon1 == lon2) return 0;
            lat1 *= DE2RA;          
            lon1 *= DE2RA;
            lat2 *= DE2RA;
            lon2 *= DE2RA;
            var d = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lon1 - lon2);
            if(isNaN(radius * Math.acos(d)))
            {
                console.log(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
            }
            //console.log((radius * Math.acos(d)));
            return (radius * Math.acos(d));
        };
```

Initially the alert returns numbers. After a certain limit it becomes NaN.

Comment: How big are the numbers?  Are you overflowing the size of the numeric?

Comment: s is a float number. Eg. s= 1.0583389964654335.

Comment: `latArray[i+1]` will throw NaN or undefined at last index, put `var i = 0;i< latArray.length-1;i++`

Comment: it is because at some point `parseFloat(s)` returns `NaN`

Comment: @ErmaIsabel I mean S at runtime ! look aj juvians comment

Comment: @juvian I tried that, it still returns NaN

Comment: Try using `if(distance==NaN){console.log(latArray[i],lonArray[i],latArray[i+1],lonArray[i+1])}`

Comment: @juvian Tried that, Each of them are float numbers

Comment: And `s` is also a float? If so, save in a variable the distance before adding and after adding put `if(distance==NaN){console.log(oldDistance)}`

Comment: @juvian s is sometimes NaN. For eg. When latArray[i] = 0.1223287393868588, lonArray[i] = 1.7536562230972799, latArray[i+1] =  0.1223287393868588, lonArray[i + 1] = 1.7536562234463458

Comment: @juvian Math.acos(1.0000000000000002) returns NaN that is the problem

Comment: Oh great you found error, just saw you GCDistance function, was about to say that trigonometry functions have limits

Comment: @juvian Will it affect the total distance if i neglect those?

Comment: Well, not sure where your data comes from but maybe its just a decimal precision issue and you could check if its > 1, equal it to 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're crossing the range.

Range is: **+/- 9007199254740992**

[ECMA Section 8.5 - Numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

Comment: Exceeding the range results in InF, not NaN - also, that's the "sequential integer precision range" range, not the maximum range which is 2^1023! e.g. see `Math.pow(2, 1023)` and `2 * Math.pow(2, 1023)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to get only numeric sum,

```
var distance = 0;
for(var i = 0;i< (latArray.length-1);i++)
{
    var s = GCDistance(latArray[i],lonArray[i],latArray[i+1],lonArray[i+1]);
    distance = parseFloat(distance) + parseFloat(s);

    alert(distance);    
}
```

if you are passing arguments to GCDistance class as float or Integer , you have to parse them to get the correct ans,

```
latArray[i],lonArray[i],latArray[i+1],lonArray[i+1]
```

(Note: Make sure values are there in latArray,ionArray,latArray,and ionArray)

Comment: I checked. Every time s returns a proper float number. It occurs at addition

Comment: Then this will be the problem of loop actually, You should run loop till latArray.length-1

Comment: try 

alert(s); after

var s = GCDistance(latArray[i],lonArray[i],latArray[i+1],lonArray[i+1]);
line

and make sure your GCDistance is working and returning a valid value,

Answer (score -1):

The (or at least a) problem is probably the issue indicated in the comments by juvian:

> latArray[i+1] will [result in undefined] at last index [..]

When the `undefined` value is used in a math expression, it is converted to a NaN. This NaN is then *propagated* through the remainder of the math operations.

Here is a demonstration of this behavior

```
var x = +undefined  // NaN -> x, as +expr results in [ToNumber(expr)]
2 + x               // 2 + NaN -> NaN, as NaN "contaminates" every math operator
```

The proposal was to only loop to `i < latArray.length-1`, such that `latArray[i+1]` is always an index access *within* the bounds of the array, although you'll have to check if this is correct.

Comment: I found the issue,  Math.acos(1.0000000000000002) returns NaN that is the problem

Comment: @ErmaIsabel What *should* the value be for `acos(1)` according to your algoritm? If you mean to simply ignore it add a conditional such as: `var t = Math.acos(d); return !isNaN(t) : radius * t : 0;` (That is, only use the value when it's not NaN, and return 0 otherwise.)

Comment: I'm confused as in, will it affect the total distance if i neglect them?